# Get a list of all xml attributes

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I'm making an API call that returns the value in `System.Xml.XmlElement`,
but it looks like this:

```
  id                       : 5847538497
  ipAddress                : 192.168.110.1
  status                   : RUNNING
  upgradeStatus            : UPGRADED
  upgradeAvailable         : false
```

Saving this in a local variable `myData`. How can I print all the attributes of this returned XML?

It works if I type:

```
> Write-Host myData.id
> Write-Host myData.status
```

but I don't know all the attributes as api call is dynamic and returns different attributes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [`Format-List`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113302) and the [`Get-Member`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113322) cmdlet:

```
myData | Format-List * -force
myData | Get-Member
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the `Attributes` property on the `XmlElement` object in question:

```
$myData.Attributes |ForEach-Object {
    'Name: {0}; Value: {1}' -f $_.LocalName,$_.Value
}
```